# remove Quotes from String in Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, makefile, command-line

I want to retrieve some Values from AWS and use them afterwards in my Makefile. But for that purpose I need to remove the quotes.
I know different ways how to do that in Linux but not in Windows. The only hint I found is this: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-dequote.html

But all my attempts to use it with my code have not worked so far.

The Code looks like this:

```
aws/project_name:
   @ $(eval PROJECT = $(shell aws ssm get-parameter --name "$(PROJECT_PARAMETER)" --query Parameter.Value))
   @set PROJECT = %~1
   @ echo $(PROJECT)
```

When I run it the result is:

```
"MyProject"
```

Can someone give me hint pls how to strip the Double-quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(eval )` is a `make` function, not something which is evaluated as part of a shell script like your snippet suggests. Moreover you need to concatenate recipe shell lines with backslash, otherwise *each line is executed in a separate shell process, thereby losing access to any variable instantiated in previous lines*.

Another issue is the use of `$(PROJECT)` without quoting: `make` will replace this with its internal `PROJECT` variables' value *before* it goes to evaluate even the first line (see below) of your recipe. If you want to access the shell variable in this line, quote every use of `$` with `$$`.

To answer your original question for replacement of `""`: `$(patsubst "%",%,$(PROJECT))` would do that - you can wrap the whole `$(shell ...)` in it. but I suspect your troubles with what you are trying to achieve will not end there.

It is rather complicated to introduce `make` variable values in a running build in the right order. I'm stressing this again: At least you must keep in mind that `make` evaluates all of its own syntax (e.g. the `$(eval )` call) always and entirely  *before it executes* the recipe. Moreover, the order of evaluation of the rule is *also* split into two phases, see here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles. If you don't understand the execution model of a makefile you will not be able to write controlled advanced scripting code in it.

One can do advanced scripting with `make` like you are trying, but I recommend a strict architectural approach for such makefiles - ad-hoc writing them will likely lead to chaos.

The current file could be written as:

```
aws/project_name: ; 
    # ';' reliably separates recipe lines from target & prerequisites
    # we still need to $(eval) PROJECT because it is only accessible for other recipes this way
    $(eval PROJECT = $(patsubst "%",%,$(shell aws ssm get-parameter --nam`enter code here`e "$(PROJECT_PARAMETER)" --profile enchomepage --query Parameter.Value))) 
    @echo $(PROJECT)     

later_target: aws/project_name
    # this should work now:
    @echo $(PROJECT)
```

...but beware, this is exactly the part where such makefiles become hard to trace, becaus now you need to mentally follow the evaluation order, take care that variables used downstream are really `$(eval )`'ed upstream (they won't if the recipe isn't executed) thereby having sidestepped the usual contract which other programmers expect from a makefile.

Comment: Thank you @Vroomfondel, that is very interesting. I read the part about execution. Now I have recreated the code and its working great. many thanks!!